# C# Remove HTML code and combine paragraph

Tags: c#, string

I have the following input:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc a dignissim purus. Curabitur enim nibh, tempor id lobortis tincidunt, adipiscing ac felis. Nunc interdum ullamcorper tortor non elementum. Praesent felis mauris, volutpat eu cursus nec, luctus vel odio.</p>

<p>Morbi elementum nunc at nulla iaculis tincidunt. Vivamus sit amet sapien vel enim lacinia ultrices sit amet ac urna. Sed semper mauris id nulla consectetur viverra. Quisque eget leo nisl. Etiam et risus sapien. Aenean vitae ante et erat tincidunt ullamcorper vel a odio. Integer hendrerit turpis et enim convallis rhoncus pharetra enim ullamcorper. Suspendisse porta mollis purus, in lacinia nunc sollicitudin vel. Nam id ligula mi.</p>
```

How can I get an output without HTML code (that's easy) but also the paragraphs combined? Like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc a
>   dignissim purus. Curabitur enim nibh, tempor id lobortis tincidunt,
>   adipiscing ac felis. Nunc interdum ullamcorper tortor non elementum.
>   Praesent felis mauris, volutpat eu cursus nec, luctus vel odio. Morbi
>   elementum nunc at nulla iaculis tincidunt. Vivamus sit amet sapien vel
>   enim lacinia ultrices sit amet ac urna. Sed semper mauris id nulla
>   consectetur viverra. Quisque eget leo nisl. Etiam et risus sapien.
>   Aenean vitae ante et erat tincidunt ullamcorper vel a odio. Integer
>   hendrerit turpis et enim convallis rhoncus pharetra enim ullamcorper.
>   Suspendisse porta mollis purus, in lacinia nunc sollicitudin vel. Nam
>   id ligula mi.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, there are plenty of dlls out there for `HTML`-`String` conversion like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/HTML_to_Plain_Text.aspx) one. But you want a customized one (which will combine the paragraphs), is there any tag used other than `<p></p>` in the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a HTML parser like [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) it is quiet easy:

```
// remove the html tags
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);
string result = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;

// remove the line breaks
result = result.Replace("\r", "");
result = result.Replace("\n", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

just read the html and replace `<p>` and `</p>` with `""` also remove the newlines (`\r\n`) and i think you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Once you have easily removed the HTML, you could then use a regular expression to remove excessive whitespace:

```
string input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur \r\n Morbi elementum nunc at nulla.";
string pattern = @"\s+";
string replacement = " ";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```